# quebrando um arquivo e armazenando em um vetor - em Java

Tags: java

Estou tentando armazenar em uma matriz os valores de um arquivo com a extensão csv. Essa extensão provém de um arquivo feito no excel, e quando salvo nesta extensão os valores são separados através de “;”.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Através desta imagem já dá para imaginar o resultado final que gostaria de chegar com a matriz.*

Na sequência, após ler o arquivo, segue minha lógica:

**1 – Quebrar linha por linha deste arquivo que leio.**

**2 – Armazenar cada linha em um único vetor usando o método split, colocando como parâmetro o delimitador (“;”).**

**3 – Passar do vetor para matriz.**

O problema é que quando vou armazenar linha por linha no vetor, armazena apenas a última linha que estou inserindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*(Print console do NetBeans)*

Ou seja, ao invés dele acumular os valores inseridos, ele está sobrepondo os valores cada vez que a sequência segue para a linha de baixo.

Bem, se eu não estou conseguindo passar desta parte, fica impossível conseguir armazenar os valores dentro da matriz.
E, por favor, eu sei que exitem outras soluções no Java para facilitar este processo. Porém, estou realmente tentando trabalhar com a lógica e recursos simples para conseguir chegar onde preciso.

**Então, a minha dificuldade está em armazenar cada valor no vetor usando o método split().**

Por fim, segue o código que já fiz!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class EntradaSaidaIO {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        String matriz[][] = new String[26][26]; // Matriz onde contém 26 linhas e 26 colunas
        int n = 26*26; //
        String linhaF[] = new String[n]; //Vetor onde deveria armazenar os valores do arquivo

        InputStream e = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Moraes\\Desktop\\MatrizApagar.csv");
        InputStreamReader er = new InputStreamReader(e);
        BufferedReader ebr = new BufferedReader(er);
        String texto = ebr.readLine(); // O método readLine()apens lê uma linha do arquivo

        while( texto != null){
            System.out.println(texto);
            linhaF = texto.split(";");
            /*
            for(int k = 0; k < linhaF.length; k++){
                System.out.print(linhaF[k]); // Apenas exibe o conteúdo dentro do vetor linhaF
            }
            */
            texto = ebr.readLine();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < linhaF.length; i++){
            System.out.print(linhaF[i]); // Exibe todo o conteúdo armazenado
        }
        ebr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem razão, tem outras formas melhores de fazer isto mas como você está colocando como requisito que não pode usar as formas melhores eu não vou arriscar a responder. Eu posso fazer algo que resolve o problema e você dizer que assim você não quer e eu perdi o trabalho. Além disto, ajudaria fornecer meios de testar se tivesse colocado os dados como texto.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o "ele está sobrepondo os valores cada vez que a sequência segue para a linha de baixo."? Salvo distração minha, me parece que em nenhum lugar do seu código as linhas da matriz estão sendo alimentadas.

Comment: bigown... É um requisito, mas caso eu veja que realmente não tem como ir pelo processo lógico, utilizo recurso numa boa. E "ter colocado os dados como texto", como assim? Ter salvo o arquivo como um .txt, e não como um .csv ? Obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Bacco... Não tem como eu alimentar uma matriz se ainda não consegui quebrar o meu arquivo e salva-lo num vetor. Para eu salvar na matriz, primeiro gostaria de salvar no vetor estes dados. O que você não entendeu é que salvando os dados no vetor, quando vai para a segunda linha do arquivo os dados que tinham sido salvos no vetor são substituídos pelos novos dados da linha seguinte do arquivo. Assim, o resultado final apresenta apenas a última linha do arquivo. Melhorou agora?

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na linha 20:

```
linhaF = texto.split(";");
```

Foi criado um vetor de 26*26 mas ele está sendo substituído a cada iteração pelo  retorno de `texto.split(";")`, que é um vetor de tamanho 26, quando a sua intenção era adicionar ele ao final.
O vetor não tem uma forma nativa (que eu conheça) para concatenar outro vetor, então você terá que fazer isso manualmente:

```
 int j = 0;
 while(texto != null){
      System.out.println(texto);
      for(String str : texto.split(";")){
            linhaF[j++] = str;                  
      }             
      ...                
 }
```

Outra forma seria trabalhar com algum tipo de Lista do java ao invés do vetor de String:

```
ArrayList<String> linhaF = new ArrayList<String<();
...
while( texto != null) {
    linhaF.addAll(Arrays.asList(texto.split(";")));
    //Arrays
    ...
}
```